# Paint player and landscape in game?

Tags: java, jpanel, repaint, performance

I'm just playing around making a little game to get some more experience in java. The panel that contains all the visual stuff has a 2 dimensional array as a grid for a tile based landscape, and i have like grass, trees, and water. In order to properly paint the right pictures on the right tiles, it takes a lot of if statements and such. It didn't look nice, so i moved all the if statements for the water tiles (determining if it was the north coast, or ocean, and so on) into their own method, but i noticed it slowed down a lot as i tried to move my character around. I realized it was stupid to be repainting the background every time i move as that pretty much stays the same. So how can I just paint the background and leave it at that, yet still repaint the sprite for the character as he moves around the panel, at a reasonable speed?

Comment: you also only have to redraw the background where the character was and now is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where I simply wanted to move a registration line across a stock chart without repainting the stock chart for ewch new position of the line.

The answer is to use a buffered image.  Paint the static parts on an image, store it as an offscreen image, then recall to screen it each time you wish to paint the moving object(s) on the image.  It's fairly easy to implement, and works very well.

Hope this helps.

John R. Doner

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel with your background image. Set the panel to a GridLayout and add JLabels to each grid. Then you can just use the setIcon(...) method of the label to move your player from grid to grid. So the basic code would be:

oldLabel.setIcon(null);
newLabel.setIcon(...);

Now Swing will look after repainting only the two grid squares that changed.